# Remove file now ignore with gitignore (only from a folder)

Tags: git

I've a problem with a project stored in a git repository. I've created three different branches (master, v1, v2) and sometimes I updates branches v1, v2  downloading the content from the master branch through this code:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout release/demo
git merge master
git push
```

In this project I've got a folder named "image" (present on all branches), and I need the contents of this folder (with some exceptions) not to be synchronized during the merge. In order to do that, I've created a .gitignore file containing this code:

```
*
!.gitignore
!placeholder_300_150.png
!placeholder_450_50.png
```

The problem is that the different branches already contain multiple versions of different files in this folder, and this causes many problems during the merge. How can I delete all versions of ignored file from my repository (if possible without working on all projects but only on this folder)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not wrong, you are wanting to ignore your `image` directory during `commit/pull/push`. For this, clear your `git cache`. Add `image` directory in your `.gitignore` file.

```
$ git rm --cached -r image

# add just image in .gitignore file
image/ 

# add, commit and push the changes to remote
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'Updated .gitignore'
$ git push origin HEAD
```

Comment: Yes it's correct, but if i remove all my git cached i cause problem in another folder. I can limit the operation to that folder?

Comment: Yes. You can remove cached for just image directory by `git rm --cached -r image`.

Comment: Thanks! I must do this on every branch, not only on master, right?

Comment: You can do this in any branch. And `merge` this branch or `cherry-pick` this commit in every other branch.